# Reflected property(dynamic property) inside Linq lambda

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

How can i replace `x.Demographic.AgeRange` with any other field?
Eg

```
var field_to_check  = "Country";
x.Demographic.ReflectedProperty(field_to_check)=="USA"



var field_to_check  = "AgeRnage";
x.Demographic.ReflectedProperty(field_to_check)=="20-30"
```

I Tried with a refelcted property. but cant succeed.

```
  Favourability = db.Questions
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Responces.Count(y => y.Responseval == Constants.options.Agree || y.Responseval == Constants.options.Tend_to_Agree))
                    .Select(z => new
                    {

                        z.QuestionTitle,
                        Count = z.Responces.Where(x =>
                                x.Demographic.AgeRange == repval &&
                                (x.Responseval == Constants.options.Agree || x.Responseval == Constants.options.Tend_to_Agree)
                        )
                        .Count()
                    })
                    .Select(z => new
                    {
                        z.QuestionTitle,
                        z.Count,
                        Perc = ((z.Count / totresponcecount) * 100)
                    }
                    )
                    .ToList();
```

so that i can write only one linq statement as dynamic filtering rather than switch statements for all required properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "with any other field"? What are you trying to achieve? This feels like a bit of an XY problem at the moment.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet,
Something like
var feild =  Country
x.Demographic.feild == repval rather than

Comment: Sorry, that's still *really* unclear. Please edit your question to be clearer - and ideally simplify the code as well, given that you've provided quite a lot of code, most of which I suspect is irrelevant. A [mcve] would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the expression tree from multiple different ones. Use LinqKit, and write:

```
Expression<Func<Demography, string>> fieldSpec = d => d.AgeRange;
```

And then in your expession:

```
var exp =  db.Questions.AsExpadable() ... fieldSpec.Expand(x.Demographic) == repval ...
```

Now all you need to do is construct the fieldSpec dynamically, which is an excercise for you :)